# Trying to edit a deleted question fails silently; there should be a banner

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

When I try to edit a question that's deleted, it just fails silently and returns me to the question page when I click the "Save Edits" button.

Instead, there should be a banner, similar to the "This question has already been edited" one, that pops up when the question is deleted.

Here's a timeline of a question where I just encountered this behavior:

1. Question is posted
2. I hit "Edit"
3. 2K+ user makes basic edits
4. Seeing the notice that the question was already edited, I hit "cancel" and reapply my edit.
5. As soon as I click "Save Edits", I get immediately returned to the question page with no indication that the question had been deleted.
6. I reload; due to caching, I fail to see that the question has been deleted. I redo the edit and hit "Save Edits" again, with the same results.
7. I clear my cache and reload (with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>); I finally see that the question has been deleted.